# What are the differences between "service" and "Factory"?

Tags: service, factory

I try to find a real diference when I need to use a Factory or a Service, but I allways find in the examples the same like:

```
a) This is the way to create the "i18n" service...
b) This is the way to create the "i18n" factory...
```

Is like put the same code in diferent order to do the same stuff. So I allways asking myself: What is the real diference if I can do the same?

And another problem is in the a lot of tutorials the people gives a diferents meaning to each term, so rigth now I'm verry confused.

So, I ask:

1. What is the meaning of a service?
2. What is the meaning of a factory?
3. What is the diferent of a service and a factory?
4. When I need to use a service?
5. When I need to use a factory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What is the meaning of a service?**

**2. What is the meaning of a factory?**

The meaning of service and factory is same i.e. they are javascript functions and are responsible to do a specific task. Angular Service service and Angular Factory service are the ways in which we can create Angular service and depending on the application need we can use either of them.

**3. What is the diferent of a service and a factory?**

In Service service, the function acts like a constructor and you don't need to initialise and return the variable, the service automatically does it for you.

```
    myApp.service("LoginService", function () {        
        this.login = function (username, password) {                
           this.isLogged = true;      
      }        
    })
```

and in controller you can access the service by using below code-

```
    LoginService.login($scope.form.Username, $scope.form.Password);        
    $scope.loggedMessage = LoginService.isLogged;
```

Whereas, in factory, you have to explicitly initialise the object and return it as below

```
    myApp.factory("LoginFactory", function () {
        var obj = {};
        obj.login  = function(username,password){            
            obj.isLogged = true;            
            return obj;
        }
        return obj;    
    })
```

and in controller you can access the factory by using below code-

```
    var obj = LoginFactory.login($scope.form.Username, $scope.form.Password);
    $scope.loggedMessage = obj.isLogged;
```

**4. When I need to use a service?**

It should be used for simple logic. It is used to register a function that will be used as constructor of an object. For example - use service to save Login details of user in an object.

**5. When I need to use a factory?**

Factory returns an instance of an object and using this object you can access factory functions. For example, you have a MathFactory with Add, Subtract, Multiply functions.